# netbeans build failed exit value 2?

Tags: c, netbeans

I have looked at some other threads on here, but haven't been able to understand what was being suggested as a solution. This is a simple Hello World program that gives this error, though I've tried inserting code I know to be sound and I still get the same result.

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Caleb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/helloworld2'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloworld2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Caleb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/helloworld2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Caleb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/helloworld2'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Caleb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/helloworld2'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: Apparently `mkdir` cannot be found in the shell console running your build. Perhaps your `PATH` was obliterated.

Comment: I thought I'd fixed the path correctly, I'm not really sure what's wrong with it. (For the record I added on C:MinGW/msys/bin/   I also tried substituting the C with H since that worked for someone else.)

Comment: Went through it with someone. Apparently a .dll was in the wrong place inside the file.